# URL convert into guzzle request

Tags: php, facebook, guzzle

i need to convert this URL into guzzle request

> explorer/?method=GET&path=930657230472626%2Fratings%3Ffields%3Dopen_graph_story%2Creviewer&version=v3.2&classic=1

the only problem is how to set multiple values for fields param as you can see it's take two values

> fields=open_graph_story,reviewer

so how i convert this into guzzle request here is request which i made so far

```
 $this->client->request('GET', "/URL", [
      'query' => [
          'fields' => ['open_graph_story', 'reviewer']
       ],
 ]);
```

Comment: `'fields' => 'open_graph_story,reviewer'` …?

Comment: hahaha that the dumps question if you look at the answer. some time your didn't see it.
Thank's please put this in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fields` parameter value is just a comma-separated string of field names, so you want to use

```
'fields' => 'open_graph_story,reviewer'
```

(With `'fields' => ['open_graph_story', 'reviewer']` you would get something like
`…&fields[0]=open_graph_story&fields[1]=reviewer` in the resulting URL, but the API just wants *one* value.)